# Тип придаточного предложения (2)

Tags: синтаксис

В этом предложении придаточное будет обстоятельственным сравнительным или изъяснительным?

*Жена моя... меняла свою веру параллельно тому, как я менял свои увлечения (А. П. Чехов "На пути").*

Comment: Смысл  правки неясен. Я полагаю, что здесь имелось в виду именно объектное значение, но совсем не изъяснительное.

Comment: Все почему-то молчат (и редактор, и автор вопроса). Разве трудно ответить?

Comment: @Sharon  Правку с объектного на изъяснит. сделал автор. Здравствуйте!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Скажите еще, пжста, почему на вашей странице картинка «падает»?

Comment: Эта картинка четырёхракурсная. В моём представлении она не падает, а движется, летит.

Comment: Спасибо  большое за ответ, теперь я тоже буду так считать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Жена моя не оставляла меня в моих скитаниях ни на минуту и, как флюгер, меняла свою веру **параллельно тому, как я менял свои увлечения**.*

Я бы спросила так: это придаточное сравнительное или сопоставительное?  Если задавать к придаточному предложению вопрос, то он будет **объектным** (в соответствии с чем, параллельно чему), но не обстоятельственным (как).

Пояснение

Чеховский герой часто менял свои увлечения: «сегодня я верую, падаю ниц, а завтра уж я трусом бегу от сегодняшних моих богов». Если ему удавалось вдохновить женщину своими идеями, то  она верила ему безоговорочно: ее вера соответствовала его увлечениям и менялась вместе с этими увлечениями.  Это значение **соответствия** одного предмета  другому (ее веры и его увлечения).

Сравнительное значение выражает союз ***подобно тому как***, однако этого значения в тексте рассказа нет.  Но можно привести в качестве примера другую ситуацию: *Жена моя  меняла свою веру,  **подобно тому как** я менял свои увлечения.* Смысл такой: Для нее изменить веру все равно что для других изменить увлечение. (В этом случае  для  сравнения можно привести и любой другой пример.)

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ПРЕДЫДУЩЕМУ АНАЛИЗУ

Это придаточное также можно считать  **приместоименным изъяснительным** (такие СПП называют вмещающими).  В этом случае придаточное относится не к опорному слову со значением речи или мысли, а непосредственно к местоимению, при этом придаточное раскрывает содержание этого местоимения, например: Весь день он занимался тем, что правил рукопись.

В то же время в таких придаточных обычно используются **союзы ЧТО и ЧТОБЫ**, но не союз КАК.  Поэтому здесь дополнительно просматривается значение времени: меняла свою веру по мере того как, параллельно тому как. Но **в первом приближении** можно сказать, что это приместоименное изъяснительное придаточное.

Сопоставительное значение, которое я указала сначала,  **не совсем подходит** к этому случаю, так как оно указывает на соответствие или несоответствие ситуаций **в общем плане**, в рассказе же указывается на параллельное изменение взглядов. Сравнительного значения здесь вообще нет.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2

Прочитала  еще раз характеристику придаточных **сопоставительных предложений**. Они находятся в переходной зоне  между СПП и ССП, БСП. Сопоставительное значение  **периферийное**:  оно часто рассматривается как **вторичное**, возникает в конкретной ситуации и поддерживается определенной лексикой и параллельностью  предикативных структур. Поэтому заданное предложение можно определить как **приместоименное изъяснительное с дополнительным значение сопоставления.**

Нужно также учитывать **общую классификацию СПП**: они делятся на две большие группы –  расчленяемые и нерасчленяемые. К нерасчленяемым относятся присловные и **приместоименные СПП**, а к расчленяемым –   большинство СПП с обстоятельственным значением, в том числе сравнительные и **сопоставительные.** Таким образом,  приместоименные изъяснительные СПП и сопоставительные СПП относятся **к разным типам** (нерасчленяемые и расчленяемые).

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение!